# How to make JavaScript find value of input on focus, clear if it's default and keep if it's new data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, focus, onblur

I've spent too many hours trying to figure this, and I've found parts of the answer here on Stackoverflow but still can't get this working.

What I want to do is control all input elements sitewide with some JS/jQuery. When a user focuses on the input, if the value is the same as when the page loaded, clear it, if it's been altered, keep it. Then on blur, if the field is empty, return the default value.

What I have so far is this:

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

$('input, textarea').focus(function() {
    value = $(this).val();

    for (var i=input.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {           
        if(value == input[i].value){
            $(this).attr("value","");   
        }   
    }
});
$('input, textarea').blur(function() {
    if($(this).val()=="") {
        $(this).val(value);
    }
});
```

This partly works, it just keeps clearing the inputs though, whether they have been changed or not. I'm guessing I am storing the initial values wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this line is the bad guy

```
if(value == input[i].value){
```

since getElementsByTagName returns a HTMLCollection, changes to the dom are also in your input variable. Thus, value will always be input[i].value, since your getting the value of the same input elem, which of course are the same!

use [jquery data method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to save the value within the element. and on blur, retrieve it again to make the comparison.

like this;

```
var handlers={
    focus: function() {
        var elm=$(this),
            value=elm.val(),
            old=elm.data("placeholder");
        if (typeof old==="undefined"){
            elm.data("placeholder", value);
            old=value;
        }
        if (old==value){
            elm.val("");
        }
    },
    blur:function() {
        var elm=$(this);
        if( elm.val() == "" ) {
            elm.val( elm.data("placeholder") );
        }
    }
};
$('input, textarea').each(function(i, elem){
    $(elem).
        focus(handlers.focus).
        blur(handlers.blur);
});
//not tested, should work!
```

Comment: +1 - Our answers are the same I think.  Can I edit your answer with my code?

Comment: thanks for the proposal - I just had written the code myself. next time, go for it :)

Comment: Hey!, this works great. Could I be really cheeky and ask if you could tell me how it works, so I can learn from it and not just copy paste? I don't quite understand how the data placeholder works and what the 'type of' is doing. 

Thanks!

Comment: thank you :) sure. Well, first off, I store the elem, improving performance. jQuery has an excellent [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/), so I know what 'data' does. if a function doesnt return anything and just does a simple `return;` at the end and the result of that function is assigned to a var, that var doesn't have anything 'in it'. Its not `null` (since thats actually an object). Its undefined and you can check that with [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof). The rest is your code, just refactored. clear? :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to store a default value first, then reference it on blur and focus.

```
$('input, textarea').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('defaultValue', $this.val()); // stores the default value

        $this.focus( function() {
            if ($this.val() == $this.data('defaultValue')) { 
                $this.val(""); 
            }
        });

        $this.blur( function() {
            if ($this.val() == "") { 
                $this.val( $this.data('defaultValue') ); 
            }
        });
});
```

With a second look, I think that we don't even need the data store.

```
$('input, textarea').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            defaultValue = $this.val(); // stores the default value

        $this.focus( function() {
            if ($this.val() == defaultValue) { 
                $this.val(""); 
            }
        });

        $this.blur( function() {
            if ($this.val() == "") { 
                $this.val(defaultValue); 
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: That's very well written. Combining the data method to the listeners with each.  Bravo

Comment: @Marlin & @natedavisolds; the readability is very good indeed! But not performance wise. Some input; all $() statements should be assigned to local vars if used +1 times, because jquery will wrap it every time. And by first doing an each and then focus and blur, your actually doing 3 loops over all elems -> make focus and blur a non-anonymous function outside of each and within each, bind the functions. (@natedavisolds -> yep, my code can be optimized as well ;) )

Comment: @japrescott - I always forget to assign to local variables.  Better now?

Comment: @natedavisolds refer to my updated code. Actually how its now, its even worse, since your creating two anonymouse functions for each element. Check out my code.. when you get it.. bricks will be shat ;)

Comment: @japrescott - I don't see what this is a bad practice please inform.

Comment: @japrescott - I think that you advocating to not create a 3 functions for each element.  That right? I wonder how much performance increase it would have over not having to check the data() and $() every time.  Any ideas on which would perform better?

Comment: @natedavisolds; for every element found, the anon function within each will be called. Each call then adds focus/blur events and passes a fn to be called in eventFire. Now, that fn passed is **created everytime** you iterate with each. Thus, the creation takes performance and your filling up memory for no reason.

Comment: @natedavisolds didnt see that comment ill now. Yeah, i'm refering to the 2 (not 3) anon fns created for each elem. Performance.. hard to say. Wrapping en element in a jquery object to just retrieve the value is for sure bad performance compared to elem.value or elem.innerHTML. The data method of jquery also creates overhead, but creating a storing mechanism or using closures to capture the initial value would be an ~equal overhead. I tend to never use jquery if possible. IMHO; jQuery is for designers, not for programmers :) but with the cpu and js engines of today.. performance isnt as crusial

Comment: @japrescott - I totally get what you are saying.  With 1000 inputs, there will be 2000 anon functions just counting for focus and blur. While there will be two, if declared outside each. I will be better with this.  But I was wondering, this there also a performance hit for using $().data and $(this) in these two functions.  I am curious how well the reaction performs with these two ways. The pattern I used is definitely worse with many, many elements.  But with 30? when focus and blur are run 30 times?  I'm not trying to argue.  I respect you a lot for your comments. It is helpful to me.

Comment: I've created a jquery plugin recently that I'd love to have you review. I like your insights. It is on code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3104/need-a-review-of-a-jquery-plugin-that-conditionally-displays-elements-based-on-fo

Answer (score 0):

this what I use on my Search box:

`<input name="q" value="Search here ..." onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search here ...') this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Search here ...';">`

Comment: this is really really bad coding; your missing </input, your javascript isn't generic and events should be added via addEventListener and not by inlining them! Additionally, this blows up the transfer size for no reason (if your using >1 input fields)

Answer (score 0):

I think @japrescott is correct, but you have another issue as well - in the block:

```
$('input, textarea').blur(function() {
    if($(this).val()=="") {
        $(this).val(value);
    }
});
```

...the variable `value` isn't defined in scope.

Answer (score 0):

So, issue 1 - that collection in input is by reference, so when your inputs are updated, they are also are updated in the collection, thus the value always appears to be the default.

What I would recommend is rather than storing the default values that way, store them as part of the element. On load you can loop through the elements and add the values to a "default" attribute. You could also add the default attribute server-side which would be better.

Something like this:

```
<input type='text' default='myval' value='myval'/>
var jInput = $('input');
if(jInput.val() == jInput.attr('default'))
...
```

I'm sure you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

this does it all:    http://jsfiddle.net/uUzY3/4/

```
$(function() {
    $("input").each( function () {
        $(this).data('initialValue', $(this).val());
    }).bind('focus', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == $(this).data('initialValue'))
            $(this).val("");
    });
});
```